# ORDEBY Python: How to print list in for loop using this libary

Tags: python, sorting, package

I'm trying to order my list using this package [orderby 0.0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orderby)

Using this command I got it to print like I wanted:

```
print json.dumps(sorted(dic, key=asc('BAIRRO').asc('RUA')), indent=2)
```

I want to print that result in a `for` loop, I tried this but it does not work:

```
for i in json.dumps(sorted(dic, key=asc('BAIRRO').asc('RUA')), indent=2)
```

Should I use list comprehension? Or other way to sort them?

Comment: my dic is a list, using for loop would be better to my users see the results. I don't know if I was clear, please tel me if something isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print each record separately, you should loop and access them like:

```
for rec in sorted(dic, key=asc('BAIRRO').asc('RUA')):
    print rec["BAIRRO"], rec["RUA"]
```

Comment: I think you meant `json.dumps(rec, indent=2)` instead of what you typed.